# MacroDroid - To only allow certain people to automatically answer calls

Tags: calls, macrodroid

I'm trying to set up a macro using MacrdoDroid to automatically answer calls whenever they occur. However, I only want it to happen when certain people call me. I've tried adding the person's name to the left of the trigger "Incoming voice/video call", and setting the search term to exact instead of contains, and it just doesn't pick it up. It works fine if only "Incoming voice/video call" is there, but not when I add someone's name.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You want to add something like "John Doe Incoming voice call"? If yes, I am not sure that Contains  or Exact would work. Better try using regular expressions.